# Can I un-warp a warped bed post?

Tags: wood-repair, restoration

I have a decorative post from a piece of furniture which has become warped -- the top has moved by something like 2 inches, at the top of a ~3foot long tapered and carved post segment. It is finished with lacquer.

Is there a way that I can un-warp this, and if so, how would I do so?

Comment: You might be able to do this successfully, as in it could be technically possible (using standard wood-bending techniques), but whether *you* could accomplish this in a cost-effective manner.... that's a really open question. We could do with a couple of pictures showing the problem to get a better idea of what has happened, how bad it is, where the warping occurred and exactly what form it takes (is it a simple bow or is there a twisting component). Just to note right from the outset, if you did want to try this the existing finish should come off and the piece will need complete refinishing.

Comment: No pictures right now, but it's definitely not twisted / it's rotationally symmetric so who knows. Refinishing doesn't seem impossible but would be hard to match the finish of the other posts. I can't get replacement parts so I don't really see an alternative to unwarping, unless it would be more cost effective to pay someone to make a duplicate of the post.

Comment: *"Refinishing doesn't seem impossible but would be hard to match the finish of the other posts. "* Yes, why I wanted to mention it right now before you embark on any efforts to straighten. Matching the colour would be bread and butter to a woodworking professional with relevant experience, or a dedicated refinisher (IF you can find one). But it's tricky to impossible work for the inexperienced, especially in some markets where it's harder to get specific finishing supplies (e.g. suitable dyes, toning lacquers).

Comment: Additionally, there is a distinctly non-zero chance that the post would warp again. That said, if you'll search here, you'll find a number of questions on "unwarping" (or straightening) and can take a look at the recommendations.